# Subset a Data Frame based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, subset

I have the following data frame (my real data frame has more rows and columns but is ostensibly structured as such):

```
Root_R1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
Root_R2 = c(1,0,3,0,0)
Root_R3 = c(1,0,3,0,0)
Shoot_R1 = c(1,0,3,4,5)
Shoot_R2 = c(0,0,31,4,5)
Shoot_R3 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
data.frame(Root_R1, Root_R2, Root_R3, Shoot_R1, Shoot_R2, Shoot_R3)

Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
1    Root    Root    Root    Shoot    Shoot    Shoot
2       1       1       1        1        0        0
3       2       0       0        0        0        0
4       3       3       3        3       31        0
5       4       0       0        4        4        0
6       5       0       0        5        5        0
```

What I would like to do is filter this data frame and find all of the rows where at least two of the columns associated with a tissue type (Root, Shoot, etc.) have values greater than 0. So, for the columns associated with "Roots" (Column 1,2,3), Rows 1 - 3 should be returned while the ones associated with "Shoots"will have Rows 4 - 6 returned. I thought a `ifelse` code would work but that seems inefficient. Would `filter` from `dplyr` be more appropriate?

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix character strings and numbers in a vector, they all become character.

Comment: Understood. If I made the same data frame but heeded your advice (dropping the "Root" and "Shoot" from my df and using "Root_R1" as a column title, would your suggested solution below change?

Comment: Yes,it would the first instruction (`df1 <- df1[-1,]`) would no longer be needed. Nor to coerce to integer in the `df1[]<-lapply` loop. This loop wouldn't hurt but it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Gotcha. And assuming I want to change the numerical value of the cut-off, I would change this part of the code ```(sum(x > 0L))``` and if I wanted to change the number of rows that meet the cut-off, I would change this: ```>= 2L```?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Or write a function. I will edit my answer predicting those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
`grep` tells the `"Root"` columns from the `"Shoot"` ones. Then `apply` loops returning logical (row) indices and `which` take care of sub-setting the data.frame.

```r
Root_R1 = c("Root",1,2,3,4,5)
Root_R2 = c("Root",1,0,3,0,0)
Root_R3 = c("Root",1,0,3,0,0)
Shoot_R1 = c("Shoot",1,0,3,4,5)
Shoot_R2 = c("Shoot",0,0,31,4,5)
Shoot_R3 = c("Shoot",0,0,0,0,0)
df1 <- data.frame(Root_R1, Root_R2, Root_R3, Shoot_R1, Shoot_R2, Shoot_R3)

df1 <- df1[-1,]
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.integer)

root <- grep("Root", names(df1))
shoot <- grep("Shoot", names(df1))
ok_root <- which(apply(df1[root], 1, \(x) sum(x > 0L) >= 2L))
ok_shoot <- which(apply(df1[shoot], 1, \(x) sum(x > 0L) >= 2L))

df1[ok_root, ]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 2       1       1       1        1        0        0
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
df1[ok_shoot, ]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 5       4       0       0        4        4        0
#> 6       5       0       0        5        5        0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

Following a [question in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565241/subset-a-data-frame-based-on-multiple-conditions?noredirect=1#comment128185275_72565241)

> And assuming I want to change the numerical value of the cut-off, I would change this part of the code (`sum(x > 0L)`) and if I wanted to change the number of rows that meet the cut-off, I would change this: `>= 2L`?

here is a function to solve the problem.

```r
special_subset <- function(x, colpattern, cutoff = 0L, numrows = 2L) {
  i_cols <- grep(colpattern, names(x))
  ok <- which(apply(x[i_cols], 1, \(y) sum(y > cutoff) >= numrows))
  x[ok, ]
}

special_subset(df1, "Root")
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 2       1       1       1        1        0        0
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0

special_subset(df1, "Shoot", cutoff = 1)
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 5       4       0       0        4        4        0
#> 6       5       0       0        5        5        0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

To pass more than one `colpattern` to the function above, use a `lapply` loop.

In the two exaples below, first I use the new pipe operator introduced in R 4.2.0 and in the second a standard `lapply`.

```r
tissue_type <- c("Root", "Shoot")

tissue_type |>
  lapply(\(pat, data) special_subset(data, pat), data = df1)
#> [[1]]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 2       1       1       1        1        0        0
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 5       4       0       0        4        4        0
#> 6       5       0       0        5        5        0

lapply(tissue_type, \(pat, data) special_subset(data, pat), data = df1)
#> [[1]]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 2       1       1       1        1        0        0
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Root_R1 Root_R2 Root_R3 Shoot_R1 Shoot_R2 Shoot_R3
#> 4       3       3       3        3       31        0
#> 5       4       0       0        4        4        0
#> 6       5       0       0        5        5        0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I assume a ```lapply``` function doing the same thing to each data frame in the list look like this: ```ok_list <- which(lapply(list, 1, \(x) sum(x > 0L) >= 2L))```?

Comment: @PatrickThomas No, `lapply` doesn't have a `MARGIN` argument, it must be `apply`. Try it and see the `1` giving an error.

Comment: Understood. I want to run this function on a data frame with several groups and I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to do so. Would a ```for``` loop be feasible if I placed all of my tissue types in a table labeled ```colpattern``` with a column titled ```colpattern$tissue_type``` and ran the following: ```special_subset <- function(x, colpattern, cutoff = 0L, numrows = 2L) {
  for (i in seq_along(colpattern$tissue_type)) {
  i_cols <- grep(colpattern, names(x))
  ok <- which(apply(x[i_cols], 1, \(y) sum(y > cutoff) >= numrows))
  x[ok, ]
} ```?

Comment: I tried placing all of my categories for my large df in a vector called ```tissuetype <- c("Roor", "Shoot")``` and drafted the following code to run on multiple columns at once ```special_subset <- {function(x,z, cutoff = 0L, numrows = 2L) {
  for (i in seq_along(z)) {
    i_cols <- grep(colpattern, names(x))
    ok <- which(apply(x[i_cols], 1, \(y) sum(y > cutoff) >= numrows))
    x[ok, ]}
  }
}
``` but got the following error:  ```Warning messages: 1: In grep(colpattern, names(x)) : argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used```.

Comment: @PatrickThomas Try `tissue_type<- paste(colpattern$tissue_type, collapse="|")` before `grep(tissue_type, names(x))`.

Comment: The vector with my tissue types is called ```tissuetype```. I tried running this as you suggested: ```special_subset <- {function(x,z, cutoff = 0L, numrows = 2L) {
  for (i in seq_along(z)) {
    colpattern<- paste(tissuetype, collapse="|")
    i_cols <- grep(colpattern, names(x))
    ok <- which(apply(x[i_cols], 1, \(y) sum(y > cutoff) >= numrows))
    x[ok, ]}
  }
}``` but got this error: ```Error in paste(colpattern, collapse = "|") : 
  argument "colpattern" is missing, with no default```

Comment: @PatrickThomas I have just updated the function, see Edit 2.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite doing what I want. If I have a vector with ```c("Roots", "Shoots")```, I want to loop through each element of the vector to get the results of the function for each element. I thought looping the items in the vector in a ```for``` loop might work but I can't get it to work, it keeps returning ```NULL```.

Comment: @PatrickThomas OK, With the original function, use a `lapply` loop, see Edit 2, revised. The new function was deleted.